# Web Hosting not Updating HTML Code

Tags: html, atom-editor, web-hosting

I just joined 000webhost today and made my first site. I started by making a simple text “Hello World!”, and when I uploaded the index.html file, it worked! However, when I try to change the HTML code in my text editor (Atom), save it, and refresh my website, nothing changes. The only way to get my website page to update and show the changes I made in the HTML code is to delete the file from the file manager, and then upload it again. What do I need to fix in order to get my website to update after making changes to the HTML code in my text editor? I also cannot see any changes in the CSS that I add. Even if I remove it from the file manager and upload it again.

Website: https://linusjlee.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: You may be editing the file locally and having to reupload/overwrite to display the changes; you’re not editing in real-time; I recommend get a program such as FlashFXP which is an amazing FTP client; you can choose atom as your default editor; right click and edit directly on the server so that updates sync instantly; for now it appears either your host won’t allow live editing via FTP or your just editing it on your local machine

Answer (score -1):

> You may be editing the file locally and having to reupload/overwrite to display the changes; you’re not editing in real-time; I recommend get a program such as FlashFXP which is an amazing FTP client; you can choose atom as your default editor; right click and edit directly on the server so that updates sync instantly; for now it appears either your host won’t allow live editing via FTP or your just editing it on your local machine

– Ilan P

Thanks so much! This works perfectly.